# Azure-Automation-Exception: Cannot bind parameter 'ScriptBlock'

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, workflow

I'm writing a runbook/workflow like below according to this [blog](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469257.aspx):

```
workflow Do-RemoteInlineScript
{
    $uri = ...
    $credential = ...

    $result = InlineScript
    {
        <commands>   
    } -PSConnectionUri $uri -PSCredential $credential
}
```

When I run it, I will get the exception **Cannot bind parameter 'ScriptBlock'.**

Where do I err?

**Note**: My problem seems to be related to this [msdn-post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8b562388-3968-4139-899a-c5353fff336a/same-kind-of-inlinescript-code-works-in-powershell-worklfow-but-fails-in-azure-automation-runbook?forum=azureautomation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Automation currently has a bug where `InlineScript` cannot target a remote system, as you are trying to do above. The workaround is to put an `Invoke-Command` in the `InlineScript` and have this cmdlet target the remote system:

```
$PSCommandResult = InlineScript {         
    Invoke-Command -ConnectionUri $Using:Uri -Credential $Using:Credential -ScriptBlock { 
        <commands>
    }
}
```

See the [`Invoke-Command` sample-runbook](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-Use-a-PowerShell-59b2e28c) for more details.

Comment: I am aware of this workaround. Do you have a reference for the bug?

Comment: Just the link you already mentioned: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8b562388-3968-4139-899a-c5353fff336a/same-kind-of-inlinescript-code-works-in-powershell-worklfow-but-fails-in-azure-automation-runbook?forum=azureautomation. I am a member of the Azure Automation team though, so I can tell you it is a bug, and not intended behavior.